# Calculate checksum in Lua

Tags: lua, checksum

I have no experience in Lua, can anyone help me calculate checksum for the following?

55 aa 00 00 fe 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 01 51 13 01 00 XX
(The XX indicates a number from 1-16 or 0x00 to 0x0f)

SUM_L and SUM_H constitute the checksum of this command frame, which is the sum of the underlined data and 0x5555. The calculation formula is as below.

SUM = 0x00 + 0x00 + 0xfe + 0x00 + 0x00 + 0x00 + 0x00 + 0x00 + 0x01 + 0x00 + 0x00 + 0x00 + 0x51 + 0x13 + 0x01 + 0x00 + XX + 0x5555, SUM = SUM_H<<8 + SUM_L (SUM_L stands for the lower 8 bits of SUM, while SUM_H stands for the higher 8 bits of SUM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
local someBytes = {0x55, 0xaa, 0x00, 0x00, 0xfe} -- and so forth
function checksum(bytes)
  local SUM = 0
  for _,v in ipairs(bytes) do
    SUM = SUM + v
  end

  SUM = SUM + 0x5555

  local SUM_H = (SUM & 0xFF << 8) >> 8
  local SUM_L = SUM & 0xFF
  return SUM_H, SUM_L
end

local highByte, lowByte = checksum(someBytes)
print(string.format("High Byte:\t0x%02X\nLow Byte:\t0x%02X", highByte, lowByte))
```

Comment: What if the input is a string like '\x00\x00\xfe\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00' and the return should be '\x57\x56' ?

Comment: then you have to get the values from the string using [string patterns](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1)

Comment: 'local someBytes = {}

for b in code:gmatch(".") do
  str = string.format("0x%02X", string.byte(b))
  table.insert(someBytes, str)
end'